# Initialize Form as Maximized in a Python FMX GUI App

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey, maximize-window

I'm making an app in the [DelphiFMX GUI Library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python). I have a Form that is being created, but it's being created as a normal window. How do I create and maximize it immediately? It should start as maximized.

This is my current code:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form'
        self.Width = 600
        self.Height = 500

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

Is there a property or function I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `WindowState` property on the `Form` like so:

```
self.WindowState = "wsMaximized"
```

This will initialize the app as Maximized. The default value for `WindowState` is `wsNormal`.

There's also `wsMinimized` to start the app as Minimized.